# MySQL ERROR: Can't update table SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am trying to implement a trigger after the insert on a table in order to update a value on another table. Basically, I need to update the time everytime an appointment is added.

The problem is that I get an error when I try to insert on appuntamento (appointment table).
This is the error that I get

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'prenotazione' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.  0.000 sec
```

Appointment table:

```
CREATE TABLE `appuntamento` (
  `idAppuntamento` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Prenotazione` int NOT NULL,
  `Servizio` int NOT NULL,
  `Impiegato` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAppuntamento`),
  KEY `Servizio_idx` (`Servizio`),
  KEY `Impiegato_idx` (`Impiegato`),
  KEY `prenotaz_1` (`Prenotazione`),
  CONSTRAINT `impiegato_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Impiegato`) REFERENCES `impiegato` (`idImpiegato`),
  CONSTRAINT `prenotaz_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Prenotazione`) REFERENCES `prenotazione` (`idPrenotazione`),
  CONSTRAINT `servizio_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Servizio`) REFERENCES `servizio` (`idServizio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Services table:

```
`CREATE TABLE `servizio` (
  `idServizio` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TipoServizio` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Descrizione` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Durata` int NOT NULL,
  `Prezzo` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idServizio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8``
```

Reservation table:

```
CREATE TABLE `prenotazione` (
  `idPrenotazione` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cliente` int NOT NULL,
  `Data` date NOT NULL,
  `OraInizio` time NOT NULL,
  `OraFine` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `CostoTotale` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPrenotazione`),
  KEY `Cliente_idx` (`Cliente`),
  CONSTRAINT `cliente_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Cliente`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`idCliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_hour 
AFTER INSERT ON appuntamento 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE durata int;
    SELECT Durata INTO @durata
    FROM servizio
    WHERE NEW.Servizio = idServizio;

    UPDATE prenotazione
    SET OraFine = OraInizio + @durata
    WHERE NEW.Prenotazione = prenotazione.idPrenotazione;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

This is the insert on Appuntamento (maybe this is the problem):

```
INSERT INTO Appuntamento( Prenotazione, Servizio, Impiegato) VALUES
((SELECT idPrenotazione from prenotazione WHERE idPrenotazione = '11'), 
(SELECT idServizio from servizio WHERE TipoServizio='Acconciatura Uomo'),
(SELECT idImpiegato from impiegato WHERE idImpiegato='2'));
```

Comment: Do you maybe have another trigger on prenotazione that makes an update to appuntamento, which triggers an update on prenotazione, which  triggers an update on appuntamento, which triggers an update on prenotazione, which  triggers an update on appuntamento, which triggers an update on prenotazione, which triggers an update on appuntamento?

Comment: No, I haven't any other trigger in my sistem